# final static attribute change.. any idea or approach?

Tags: java, static, final

I have to maintain a code to add more flexibility to a final static variable in a class.

The variable is no more a global constant and may be changed.

The problem is that the class is in a common library and used in different projects.

Do you have an approach or a design pattern better than copying and pasting the class code from the common library to my specific application and refactoring it?

Example:

Commons project

```
Class CommonClass {

    public final static var globalSomething = somethingGlobal;

    public static method(){ //CommonClass.globalSomething is used here}
}
```

In my App (and other apps that reference commons) we can use the static attribute and also call the method:

---> `var b = CommonClass.somethingGlobal;`

---> `var c = CommonClass.method() //we know that CommonClass.globalSomething is used here`

Expectations:

- Ability to change CommonClass.somethingGlobal in my app and take these changes in call CommonClass.method()
- I can modify (add methods) in the common class but i have to keep the same initial behavior (not to break other project referencing common project)

Comment: What IDE are you using?  In Eclipse and Intellij there's some awesome refactoring.

Comment: your question is a bit vague. can you add some code, or try reqording your qeustion?

Comment: I don't get your problem either. What's wrong with just removing the `final` modifier, building a new version of your library and using it in the other projects?

Comment: If i remove final, it still static (unsafe for multithread)

Comment: Note that the Java compiler can treat some `static final` fields as compile-time constants - if you have a `public static final double THRESHOLD = 0.5` (for example), and you modify the value or remove the `final` modifier, then you will probably have to re-compile any other classes that refer to this field as they will have had the previous value "baked-in" at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to implement this as a parameter.

Looking at your example:

```
var c = CommonClass.method() //we know that CommonClass.globalSomething is used here
```

there is already something wrong with it. You shouldn't have to know that you have to set `CommonClass.somethingGlobal` correctly before calling the method. This way the client has to know the implementation, violating the principle of information hiding. If the value is required, introduce it as parameter:

```
Class CommonClass {

    public static void method(var globalSomething){}
}
```

An alternative would be making both your variable and your method non-static and use a constructor:

```
Class CommonClass {

    public var globalSomething = somethingGlobal;

    public CommonClass(var globalSomething) {
        this.globalSomething = globalSomething;
    }

    public void method(){}
}
```

PS: Your example code is not java. I corrected it partially in my answer.